# Boot problem ubuntu and windows7

Tags: boot, windows, windows-7

I install **ubuntu12.10** than I install **windows 7** and now I have access only at windows :(
i didn't find any solution for this...
can you help me please?

thanks

Comment: windows wiped Grub loading in the MBR most likely.  You need to use a live cd to reinstall grub.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use EasyBCD to solve it.
First, if you don't have this software, let start Windows, search and download EasyBCD from Web and then install it.
Start EasyBCD, choose Add New Entry, then tab Linux/BSD
In Type, choose GRUB 2
In Name, change name (Optional)
In Device, choose your Ubuntu's partition
Click Add Entry.
Then restart your computer.

Hope it help.